# Javascript trouble with XMLhttpRequest, FormData and input type='file'

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, xmlhttprequest, form-data

The object is to send two files to a PHP server to see if they are the same.
The server is to sends a message, either the two files are the same
or listing the first line (counting new line characters) where they differ
with the content of that line from both files for visual comparison.
First the code - in JAVASCRIPT

```
var OFC

function CompFiles() {
  OFC = document.getElementById('FC')
  OFC.innerHTML = '<i>comparing files at a web site</i>'
  FD = new FormData()
  t = document.getElementsByName('file1')
  t = t[0]
  v = t.value
  if (v == '') {
    OFC.innerHTML = '<red>file 1 has not beed selected yet</red>'
    t.focus()
    return
  }
  FD.append('file1', t)
  t = document.getElementsByName('file2')
  t = t[0]
  v = t.value
  if (v == '') {
    OFC.innerHTML = '<red>file 2 has not beed selected yet</red>'
    t.focus()
    return
  }
  FD.append('file2', t)
  RQ = new XMLHttpRequest()
  RQ.open("Post", 'comp03.php')
  RQ.onload = (progress) => {
    CheckSt(RQ)
  }
  RQ.open("Post", 'comp03.php')
  RQ.send(FD)
}

function CheckSt(RD) {
  O = OFC
  if (RD.status == 200) O.innerHTML = '<blue>' + RD.responseText + '</blue>'
  else O.innerHTML = '<red>Problem XMLHttpResponse = ' + RD.status == 200 + '</red>'
}
```

then in < body >

```
<p>See if two files are equal. See first line where they differ<br>
First file: <input type='file' name='file1'> Second file: <input type='file' name='file2'>
<button onclick='CompFiles()'>compare the two files</button><br>
<span id='FC'>&nbsp;</span></p>
```

The files are not showing in the PHP, count($_FILES) is zero. count($_POST) is also zero.
What am I doing wrong? I suspect there is something wrong with the FD.append, but what?
Below is how I got program almost to work the way I want it

```html
function CompFiles()    {
OFC=document.getElementById('FC')
OFC.innerHTML='<i>comparing files at a web site</i>'
data=document.querySelector('#CompFiles')
delete data.target
FDt = new FormData(data)
FR = new FormData()
FDx=FDt.entries
for A of FDx    {
    if (a.length==2) FR.append(A[0],A[1])
    else FR.append(A[0],A[1],A[2])
RQ=new XMLHttpRequest()
RQ.responseType='text'
RQ.open("Post",'comp03.php')
RQ.onreadystatechange = () => {CheckSt(RQ)}
RQ.send(FR)
return false
}
function CheckSt(RD)    {alert('CheckST')
O=OFC
if (RD.readyState === XMLHttpRequest.DONE) {
    status = RD.status;
    if (status === 0 || (status >= 200 && status < 400))
        O.innerHTML='<blue>'+RD.responseText+'</blue>')
    else O.innerHTML = '<red>Problem XMLHttpResponse status = '+status+'</red>'}
}
```

For some reason the function CheckSt is never invoked. Note I copied just what I wanted from formData(form) to another formData. It didn't seem to make much difference. Acting like XMLHttpRequest was submitted, I want response to show up in original screen. Below is what I did to < body > section to make it work.

```html
<form name='CompFiles'  action='comp03.php' method='post' enctype='multipart/form-data'>
<p>See if two files are equal. See first line where they differ<br>
First file: <input type='file' name='file1' required> Second file: <input type='file' name='file2' required>
<input type='submit' onclick='CompFiles()' value='compare the two files'><br>
<span id='FC'>&nbsp;</span></p>
</form>
```

I'd rather not use 'form', that's what original question was about.

Comment: You know you've got `RQ.open` twice? not sure that's the cause of the issue, but it doesn't make sense, at any rate

Comment: Anyway can you show the PHP code as well please

Comment: removed extra open - no difference - found workaround so PHP seems to work - see next comment for new problem

Answer (score 0):

the code looks so confusing but honestly, it's very cool

but why not use fetch, like so:

```js
fetch("link/to/comp03.php", {
method: "POST",
body: FD
})
.then(res => {
CheckSt(res);
return res.json() // or you can decide to return the res.json() from inside CheckSt fn, and in that case you would be returning CheckSt like: return CheckSt(res)
})
.then(data => {
  // if the php returns a proper json data it should be available for use here
})
.catch(err => {
// do things here if an error occured
})
```

I hope this is helpful

Comment: Yes it's often a good idea to use a newer library, but how would this fix the specific problem in the question?

Comment: have you tried it?, try it first then you'll understand the function, and I would suggest you use modern libraries, fetch is not an external library, it is built into javascript and it is modern, if you want to use library, one of the best options is Axios, it is actually not recommended to use `new XMLHttpRequest()` for AJAX requests, as far as I know I haven't seen any company that will ask you to use it during interviews

Comment: I think you may have mistaken me for the person who asked the question. I did not ask it. I know perfectly well what fetch() is, compared to XHR. But to make a good-quality answer here, you should not just dump code and say "try this", you need to explain _why_ it's a good idea to use it, and _specifically_ why it would solve the particular issue mentioned in the OP's question. Otherwise it's just a hit-and-hope solution, with no real rationale. While in general fetch() is great, it's hard to see how it would provide a fix for this particular scenario - so please clarify. See also [answer].

Comment: lol XD I'm sorry I thought you're the one that asked the question, the reason why I didn't explain it is because I assumed that the person who posted the question should already know things about AJAX and would also be able to get a quick understanding of my answer and I actually also thought of explaining my answer but no explanations came into my head that's why I decided to just dump my answer , but I will check how the How to Answer link you sent, thanks.

Comment: I just checked the question again and I can see alot of issues, I will update my answer later maybe in the next 5 - 8 hours cuz I'm busy rn

Comment: I changed to be in a form and changed code to

Comment: data=document.querySelector('#CompFiles')
delete data.target
FDt = new FormData(data)
``` Working almost, but instead of getting XMLHttpRequest response it is acting like I submitted the form (I wanted to put the response in the original screen.)

Comment: @HowardCaryMorris please edit your question to show the changes you made instead of putting things out of context (and unformatted) into the comments. Then we can see clearly what's happening now, and exactly what error you're getting. Thanks.